# Postgresql count from multiple columns in a row

Tags: postgresql, count

I have this table on a postgres db (**proofs**). proof_1, proof_2 and proof_3 are boolean columns indicating whether the user (user_id) has submitted the proofs:

| user_id | proof_1 | proof_2 | proof_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | true | true | false |
| 2 | true | false | false |
| 3 | true | true | true |

I need to count how many proofs are submitted by each user. This is the query that I came up:

```
> select 
    user_id,
    length(
      concat(
        case when proof_1 then '1' end,
        case when proof_2 then '1' end,
        case when proof_3 then '1' end)
      )) as proof_counts
  from
    proofs
```

The query above would work. But I don't think that it is the best query to do. Please advice on what query should be done?

Comment: Lots of ways to do this.  One is `proof_1::int + proof_2::int + proof_3::int`.  If you want something that can handle a variable number of `proof_X` columns, please say so as that can be done using `to_jsonb()` and `jsonb_each()` to pivot columns to rows.

Comment: Thank you.... I think this should be the answer.

Comment: Do you need the general case?  I am procrastinating from some other stuff I need to do :-) so I put up an example:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8afd7e55f440827f3a63fbc160413d48

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select user_id, 
      case when proof_1 then 1 else 0 end 
    + case when proof_2 then 1 else 0 end        
    + case when proof_3 then 1 else 0 end  as proof_counts   
 from (
    values (1,true,true,false), (2,false,true,false)
  ) as proof (user_id, proof_1, proof_2, proof_3)
```

If there is no null values then below query

```sql
select user_id, 
      proof_1::integer 
    + proof_2::integer 
    + proof_3::integer   as proof_counts   
 from (
    values (1,true,true,false), (2,false,true,false)
  ) as proof (user_id, proof_1, proof_2, proof_3)
```

And version which handle nulls

```sql
select user_id, 
      coalesce(proof_1::integer,0) 
    + coalesce(proof_2::integer,0) 
    + coalesce(proof_3::integer,0)   as proof_counts   
 from (
    values (1,null,true,false), (2,false,true,false)
  ) as proof (user_id, proof_1, proof_2, proof_3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is also a good alternative:

```
select user_id, 
       sum(case when proof_1 = true then 1 else 0 end) + sum(case when proof_2  = true then 1 else 0 end) + sum(case when proof_3 = true then 1 else 0 end) as proof_counts
    from proofs
    group by user_id
```

Comment: this could be one way. But not elegant imho...

Answer (score 0):

This is possible just by converting your boolean to integer and then summing the three columns

Query:

```
select
userid_id,
sum(case when proof_1=true then 1 end)+sum(case when proof_2=true then 1 end)+sum(case when proof_2=true then 1 end) as total_proofs_submitted
from proofs
group by user_id
```